# ETL process between two Postgres Databases

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, etl

I have **two postgres databases**, let's called them `layer 1` and `layer 2`, that both are hosted on a separate servers. In between, there is a *third server*, that first, loads tables from `layer 1`, second, applies transformation on them and third, saves the modified data to `layer 2`.

From time to time, tables in **layer 1 are truncated** and filled with **possibly recent data**. Unfortunately, our inbuild architecture does not allow to do some sort of synchronization of `layer 1` with the source data. That is, `layer 1` is always cleared and filled with all available data again. There might be new rows or new values in existing rows or no changes at all.

With now having two databases of the same technology, i.e. both postgres, I was wondering if there is any existing logic that allows me to only process rows from layer 1 that have changed or are new since the last transformation from `layer 1` to `layer 2`. I know that there are things like triggers that track insert, update or delete changes. However, if I re-enter a row into `layer 1` with the exact same column values as before, I do not want to process the row.

Any ideas how to efficiently track the required changes?